# issue about crash application in 2.3 android version with action bar

Tags: android, xml, android-2.3-gingerbread, android-actionbar-compat

I have developed an application and in this application I use `action bar` and `WebView` when I check on android version 3.2 and higher version it worked fine but when I run that application on android version 2.3 its going to crash application so what is reason of crashing application

my code is here

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;


public class about extends Activity
{

    private ImageView img;
    @Override
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")


    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.about_main);

        ActionBar ab=getActionBar();
        ab.setTitle("About");
        ab.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);


        img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.iv);
        img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE);
                intent.setData(Uri.parse("http://earthcorporation.co.in"));
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId())
        {
            case android.R.id.home :

                finish();
                return true;

            default:

                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }


    }
}
```

manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.earth.satbara_gujarat"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/satbar_icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.earth.satbara_gujarat.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.earth.satbara_gujarat.about"></activity>
        <activity android:name="com.earth.satbara_gujarat.feedback"></activity>


<activity android:name="com.mopub.mobileads.MoPubActivity" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"/>
<activity android:name="com.mopub.mobileads.MraidActivity" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"/>
<activity android:name="com.mopub.mobileads.MraidBrowser" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"/>
<activity android:name="com.mopub.mobileads.MraidVideoPlayerActivity" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"/>

<activity
      android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
      android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />


</application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: If supporting API levels lower than 11:
`import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar` for that you need to setup `appcompat v7 support library`

Comment: when i import v7 support library its showing mismatch error

Comment: remove this `import android.app.ActionBar` and add `import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of `Activity` u have to extends `ActionBarActivity` of  `appcompat v7 support library`

and import this

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
```

instead of

```
import android.app.Activity;
```

use `getSupportActionBar()` not `getActionBar()`

```
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
```

[More about ActionBarActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarActivity.html)
that will solve ur problem

Comment: showing error on main class The hierarchy of the type about is inconsistent

Answer (score 3):

If supporting **API levels lower than 11**:

> import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar

And you implement like

```
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
```

If supporting only **API level 11 and higher**:

> import android.app.ActionBar

And you implement like

```
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
```

So before you can add the action bar, you must set up your project with the `appcompat v7 support library` by following the instructions in the [Support Library Setup](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html). and for more information go to [actionbarcompat](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2013/08/actionbarcompat-and-io-2013-app-source.html)

Comment: i already import android.support.v7.app.actionbar library in my project

but its showing mismatch error while I make instance of action bar it showing error

type mismatch: cannot convert from android.app.ActionBar to android.support.v7.app.ActionBar

Comment: @PranavLathigara clean and built your project and try

Comment: @M D  its sowing error Type mismatch: cannot convert from android.app.ActionBar to android.support.v7.app.ActionBar

Comment: @PranavLathigara where u got this error?in u r Activity?

Comment: @M D ActionBar ab=getActionBar();

Comment: @PranavLathigara post u r `manifest.xml` and here u ned to add `ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();`. please first u read my answer caefully

Comment: @M D but there i didnt use getsupportActionBar()

Comment: @PranavLathigara u must used this `ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();` instead of `ActionBar ab=getActionBar();` if u want run this a in <=2.3.3

Comment: dont put that as an answer

Comment: @PranavLathigara y u put manifest.xml as answer? try yo update your question instead

Comment: @M D i try  that but i am not able to use it when i am using this its showing error

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to support action bar in lower versions , you should use ActionBarCompat or SherlockActionBar support libraries.

http://actionbarsherlock.com/

http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2013/08/actionbarcompat-and-io-2013-app-source.html

All you need to do is extends your activity with SherlockActivity instead of Activity and use getSupportActionBar() instead of using getActionBar().

You can use action bar themes for hollow look. I personally prefer SherlockActionBar over ActionBarCompat